# Symfony 3 Changing a Submit label from a Form class inside of controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I have a form that is created in it's own class:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/CoffeeShopForm.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
...

class CoffeeShopType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ...
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create a coffee shop'))
        ->getForm();
    ;
}

}
```

And then I am using it in one controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/edit/{coffee_shop_id}")
 */
public function editCoffeeShopAction(Request $request, $coffee_shop_id)
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:CoffeeShop');

    $coffeeshop = $repository->find($coffee_shop_id);

    $form = $this->createForm(CoffeeShopType::class, $coffeeshop);

    $form->get('name')->setData('New name value');

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:CoffeeController:edit_coffee_shop.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

So in the controller as you may see I am able to change the value of the name field with $form->get('name')->setData('New name value');
My question is how may I change the label of the SubmitType field - I searched for the documentation of this thing but I can't find it, and it is really helpful if I could reuse this form since I am using it for the add form and then for the edit form and basically it is possible in Zend Framework, so I think it should be possible also in Symfony

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I actually found this before. My question is more: is it not possible to be made just with something similar as $form->get('name')->setData() . Something like set label, or if there is a special structure of the argument in setData() for submit's label

Comment: The approaches you can use are in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893735/symfony2-form-type-how-to-set-form-css-class-as-attribute/22896777

Answer (score 4):

I have stumbled across the same question, and after extensive debugging, I can say with some confidence that what you want to do is not possible, at least in Symfony 2.8 .

However, what you can do is setting another label when rendering the form:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, { 'label': 'Test 123'}) }}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#label for details.

Comment: I think it's easier, faster and more maintainable to do it in Twig like this. Thanks for sharing.